# Showing X and Y Axis Labels?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, charts, data-visualization

I am using [System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a chart, but I can't figure out how to add axis labels to it. I want to show labels like so:

```
              |
              |
              |
              |
 Y-Axis Label |
              |
              |
              +----------------------------
                      X-Axis Label
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't work when adding a new `ChartArea`:

```
ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
chartArea.AxisX.Name = "X Axis";
chartArea.AxisY.Name = "Y Axis";
chartArea.AxisX.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = true;
chartArea.AxisY.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
chartArea.AxisY.LabelStyle.Enabled = true;
```

So how can I add and show labels to a chart's axes?

Comment: Did you try using the [`Axis.Title` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.title%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @admdrew That did the trick! Many thanks! ...I use Intellisense a lot and I couldn't for the life of me figure out what it was called since I kept searching for strings containing "label"!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done using the [`Axis.Title` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.title%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
chartArea.AxisX.Title = "X Axis";
chartArea.AxisY.Title = "Y Axis";
```